# Div inside span CKEditor converts to another structure

Tags: symfony, ckeditor

I want to paste this:

```html
<span class="js-contacts-popup-content hidden-block">
    <div class="popup-large-text">
        <p>1</p>
        <p>2</p>
    </div>
</span>
```

But CKEditor convert it:

```html
<div class="popup-large-text">
<p><span class="js-contacts-popup-content hidden-block">1</span></p>

<p><span class="js-contacts-popup-content hidden-block">2</span></p>
</div>
```

I set `allowedContent:true`
Multiple variants with extraAllowedContent, but have no result